# Transfer radio button from webform to another form using VB.net and ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I wrote the below code which transfer the radio button value and check box value to another HTML form but i did not find solution to transfer the radio button or check box at all to another form not only the selected value.

I want the radio button to be transfered to another form as below not only the value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCUaf.png)

```
Dim Gender As String = RadioButton1.SelectedValue
Response.Redirect("PrintPreview.aspx?"&Gender=" + Gender)
Label1.Text = Request.QueryString("Gender")
```

The code only returned the radio button value

Please advise

Comment: `RadioButton` does not have a `SelectedValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the FIRST thing, and MOST important thing to realize here is that when you execute a response.Redirect ?

```
It STOPS code running in the current page.
No code AFTER the Response.Redirect will run
All variables, and code and ALL values for the current page are destroyed!
```

So, you can't write (normally) code to run after the response.Redirect.

So, say we have this markup:

```
      <br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" 
            Font-Size="Larger" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Done" />
```

And our page now looks like this:

[image]

Now, we want to jump to page 2.

So our code can say look like this in our Test1 page.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Gender As String = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text

    Response.Redirect("Test2.aspx?&Gender=" & Gender)
    ' code AFTER above line WILL NOT run!!!!

End Sub
```

So, we can't have code AFTER the response.Redirect.

Again, read this 5 times:

```
when the response.Redirect is used, then the current page code STOPS,
and ALL values, and even your code variables are DESTROYED!!! This is not much
different then when you get to the end of a subroutine - when you exit, then all
values and things in that subroutine are "gone", and "do not exist".
```

The same goes for your web page - using Response.Redirect means STOP code, transfer to another page.

So, now above will jump to page Test2, we want to take that value we passed, and do this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        ' save a label on this page to the passed choice
        Label1.Text = Request.QueryString("Gender")

    End If

End Sub
```

Also, note close your syntax for the string you were passing in Response.Redirect was also incorrect.